# Best naming convention for handling multiword Django models?

Tags: django

What is the best naming convention for instance, url and template names of Django models with more than one word?

**Instances**

1. `yetanothermodel = YetAnotherModel()`
2. `yet_another_model = YetAnotherModel()`

**Url names**

1. `'yetanothermodel_detail'`
2. `'yet_another_model_detail'`

**Template names**

1. `'yetanothermodel_detail.html'`
2. `'yet_another_model_detail.html'`

Comment: what's the default template (if not specify) in class based views for YetAnotherModel()? is it yetanothermodel_detail.html? or yet_another_model_detail.html?

Comment: It's `yetanothermodel_detail.html`. Generic views use `YetAnotherModel._meta.model_name`, which doesn't include underscores in the name: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L144

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is your personal choice. But if you are working in a team I would say you should be applying the Python [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36) standard of coding; that way all members of the team are using the same process and naming conventions to write their code.

In this instance:

```
yet_another_model = YetAnotherModel()
```

[Variables names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) should be lower-case, underscore separated. With [class names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) using the camel casing naming convention.

and

```
'yet_another_model_detail'
```

Url names should be treat like a [variable name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) or [function name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names), lower-case separated with _ (underscores).

Templates:

Whilst there is no defined naming convention for templates I treat the naming the same as a function name. So in these cases I go for lower-case with underscore word separation.
I also keep the templates inside of the django apps (sometimes, I will have a templates directory which will have a directory for each app name).

I also stick the CRUD type at the end of the filename.

For example:

```
<app_div>/user_profile.html
<app_dir>/user_profile_update.html
<app_dir>/user_profile_view.html
<app_dir>/user_profile_delete.html
```

Comment: That's my preference too, but it is less consistent with the default template names for Class Based Views.  I've updated my answer to include them in the question too.